# Lord shiva is called shankara, mayobhava, mayaskara,shambhava, etc in vedas. Can i get their description according to shilpashastra

Tags: shiva, shilpa-shastras

I want description of lord shiva according to different shilpashastra

Comment: What are shilp shastra, example do mahabharat qualify

Comment: Rupamandana,Viśvakarma-śilpa,Rudrayāmala,Aṃśumadbhedāgama,Śrītatvanidhi, etc. Are shilpashastra. Mahabharat can also be counted if it gives description of different forms of shiva like sthanu,dhurjati,mahandeva etc.